# Firebase rules fail on batch set

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following security rule on a particular document:

```
match /items/{itemId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/items/$(itemId)) == false || request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
}
```

This works when I do a `set()` on that collection. But it fails when I do a `set` in a `batch` with following error:

```
Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I am assuming my security rule needs to be changed to handle batch writes, but there is no documentation on it. Any pointers?

**Update**:
Here is the minimal code that reproduces the problem -> https://firestore-batch-test.firebaseapp.com/ (All JavaScript inline on the page).

Exact rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /items/{itemId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/items/$(itemId)) == false || request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Batch writes are nothing more than writes that are committed or rejected as a single operation. You don't need to do anything special for them in your security rules. Please show the [minimal code that reproduces the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated the issue also. Here is the minimal code to reproduce the problem -> https://firestore-batch-test.firebaseapp.com/ 
After hours of debugging, I finally concluded that batch set with max 3-4 item works. Try setting more than 5 count there and do a batch set, it fails.

Comment: Hmmm.... I vaguely recall there being a maximum number of documents read in security rules, but can't find it in the docs right now.

Comment: That has to be 3, because thats where it fails :) Any recommended workaround for this limitation?

Comment: I asked around. In the realtime database you'd have `newData`, which contains the data as it'll exist after all writes in the batch (multi-location update in RTDB). But on Firestore that doesn't exist. Someone is looking into what it'd take to implement this, but as usual: no timeline, no commitments for that. There is no workaround that you can do in the client for it right now, but you could of course use Cloud Functions to ensure that at least the code doing the write is trusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit:

One can now get the data after it has been updated by calling `getAfter(path).data`. But that's for single document only, and by knowing the exact path of the updated document.

---

Unfortunately this is not possible on Firestore right now.

In the realtime database you'd have `newData`, which contains the data as it'll exist after all writes in the batch (multi-location update in RTDB).  But on Firestore that doesn't exist.

Someone is looking into what it'd take to implement this, but as usual: no timeline, no commitments for that.

There is no workaround that you can do in the client for it right now, but you could of course use Cloud Functions to ensure that at least the code doing the write is trusted.